# How give a specific to a command and call it by its name later

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Is it possible to give a command an specific name and call it by its name instead of write the whole command in the terminal ?
For example
when I want to start an openvpn session I have to type this command in the terminal

```
$ openvpn3 session-start --config /home/user1/Downloads/myconfiguration.ovpn
```

Is there any way to give it a name like `vpn-start` and call tihs command by its name ?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an [alias](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/alias.1posix.html) for it

Run the command
`vim ~/.bashrc` to open your `.bashrc` and add `alias shortName="your command here"`

In your case, add:

```
alias vpn-start="openvpn3 session-start --config /home/user1/Downloads/myconfiguration.ovpn"
```

You can then use `vpn-start` shortcut to open your VPN session

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) three ways to do what you want.

- Create aliases. These are usually used for simple command substitutions or one-liners. Additional arguments are added to the end of the command. They are usually placed in `~/.bash_aliases`, which is called from `~/.bashrc` when you open a new terminal.

  ```
  alias name='command arguments'
  ```
- Create bash functions. These are usually used in scripts. If put in `~/.bashrc`, they can be called directly by the user. Arguments can be referred to as in scripts, so that different commands can operate on them.

  ```
  function name {
      command1 "$2"
      command2 "$1"
  }
  ```
- Create a script file in your path (eg, `~/.local/bin/script.sh`). Don't forget to `chmod +x`:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env sh

  command1 "$1"
  shift
  command2 "$1"
  shift
  command3 "$@"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using something like [xiota mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/1276284/527764) for a long time but much simplified. I've used it with 3 VPNs including openvpn and it works fine. All you need is a text editor and the `sh` command.

1. create `sh` script file in Home directory for example name it `vpn.sh` with the script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   #vpn connection

   openvpn3 session-start --config /home/user1/Downloads/myconfiguration.ovpn
   ```

and save it. You can replace launch command for any vpn with proper path.

Now run in terminal:

```
sh vpn.sh
```

That is it. You should be connected.

Comment: It seems odd to specify bash as the interpreter in the shebang line and then run the script with `sh`, which on Ubuntu by default calls the dash shell...

Comment: well, I've been using it for quite some time, something I got used to and it works